# Using Decimals in C#

Tags: c#, decimal

```
 private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int x = 0;
            if (Int32.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out x))
            {
                var y = 1000000;
                var answer = x * y;

                displayLabel2.Text = answer.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                displayLabel2.Text = "error";
            }
        }
```

All of this code works. But I don't know how to use it if a decimal is inputed. Currently it reads numerical values fine and calculates them fine. But I need it to allow decimal points to be inputted. 
Ex. if someone inputed 4.7, then I need 4.7 to be multiplied by 1000000.

Comment: `decimal.TryParse` instead of `Int32.TryParse`

Comment: `Float` and `Double` classes.

Comment: @cubrr, `Float` and `Double` are not classes

Comment: @Habib My bad, `Single` and `Double` structs.

Comment: 4.7 whats? Dollars? Use `decimal`. Miles? Use `Single`.

Comment: Use NumericUpDown instead of TextBox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a number type that has precision.  You can use either floating types ([double](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9.aspx) or [float](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1e65aza.aspx)) or the [decimal type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx).

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    decimal x = 0;
    if (decimal.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out x))
    {
        var y = 1000000.0M;
        var answer = x * y;

        displayLabel2.Text = answer.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        displayLabel2.Text = "error";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use decimal instead of int:

```
decimal x = 0;
if (decimal.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out x))
```